# Почему в php рефлексия показывает что интерфейс это абстрактный класс?

Tags: php, интерфейс, рефлексия, php5

Можете, пожалуйста, подсказать почему в php 5.6.30 данный код:

```
interface IInterface {
  public function someMethod();
  public function anotherMethod();
}
function classData( ReflectionClass $class )
{
    $details = "";
    $name = $class->getName();

    if ( $class->isInterface() ) {
        $details .= "$name -- это интерфейс<br>";
    }

    if ( $class->isAbstract() ) {
        $details .= "$name -- это абстрактный класс<br>";
    }
    return $details;
}

$class_info = new ReflectionClass('IInterface');
echo classData($class_info);
```

выводит следующий результат:

```
IInterface -- это интерфейс
IInterface -- это абстрактный класс
```

Т.е. почему интерфейс определяется как абстрактный класс?

Если удалить методы из интерфейса, то отобразится:

```
IInterface -- это интерфейс
```

---

Интересный факт: [hhvm лишён этого недостатка](https://3v4l.org/9f7p6)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Существует 2 типа «абстрактности» в php:

- explicit - класс, явно определённый, как `abstract`.
- implicit - класс/интерфейс, содержащий абстрактные методы.

Проверить на explicit абстрактность можно так:

```
if ($class->getModifiers() &  ReflectionClass::IS_EXPLICIT_ABSTRACT) {
   // Перед нами абстрактный класс
}
```

[Демонстрация](https://3v4l.org/mvh32)